# My question was held off by vote for wrong reasons

Tags: support, closed-questions, homework-and-exercises, close-reasons

I was asking for a *clarification*.

1. [My question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/225112/) was not *Homework type*.
2. I had *worked out a solution* myself.

Answer (score 7):

In [your question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225112/electric-field-at-a-distance-above-one-end-of-a-straight-line-segment-of-a-unifo), what you actually ask is

> ...is my answer right? or is there a mistake in the calculation. Kindly discuss.

Asking whether your answer is right is not on topic here. That's why it was put on hold.

If you focus your question more on *why* you think your answer might not be right, that would be a good start toward writing a better question for this site (and perhaps getting it taken off hold).

Comment: Thank you, I will see to it that I add it in the topic.